# I want to print the names of files present in a directory as a list using ansible

Tags: python-2.7, ansible

```
---
  - hosts: localhost
    user: root

    tasks:
    - command: "ls /root/Tmp/Deployment/script_files/Hotfix"
      register: dir_out

    - debug: msg="The hotfix ids are: {{dir_out.stdout_lines}}"
```

The output I got was:

[image: My output]

but I want it as

```
The hotfix ids are :["1001","1002"]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Your playbook, the result, and your expected string are all fabrications. They have `:` in different places and the playbook won't run because of that character; the result includes `|list` not present in the playbook; your expected string contains double-quotes (with no explanation if it's a requirement). When you ask questions on StackExchange, you are supposed to include **verifiable** code.

Comment: The playbook is verifiable. How else would I be able to produce an output.

Comment: I have actually got a solution for this also.
I needed to change:
{{dir_out.stdout_lines}} to {{dir_out.stdout_lines|join(',')}} and output prints in the desired manner.

Comment: The output you included has little to do with the playbook, which I already pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change: `{{dir_out.stdout_lines}}` to `{{dir_out.stdout_lines|join(',')}}`